# Why is a typed .NET array not a generic type? (i.e. SomeType[] != Array{SomeType})

Tags: c#, excel, extension-methods, com-interop, excel-interop

[BACKGROUND:]
To make programming against Excel's interop API easier I've created a lot of extension methods for common tasks.  Many of these are LINQ-style methods for Excel's collection objects like Workbooks, Sheets, etc.  All the extension methods are in one assembly, and I reference that assembly in any application or add-in that needs the methods.  Both the extension methods assembly and the target applications embed the interop types from the same primary interop assembly.  Everything is written in C# on .NET 4.0 and referencing PIA version 15.

I just created some extension methods for the ListObjects interface and they are giving me the compiler error, "Member X from assembly Y.dll cannot be used across assembly boundaries because it contains a type which has a generic type parameter that is an embedded interop type."

Here is the method that causes the error:

```
public static IEnumerable<ListObject> Where(this ListObjects me,Func<ListObject, Boolean> condition) {
    var list = new List<ListObject>();
    foreach (ListObject x in me)
        if (condition(x)) list.Add(x);
    return list;
}
```

Here is a similar method that works:

```
public static IEnumerable<Workbook> Where(this Workbooks me, Func<Workbook, Boolean> condition) {
    var list = new List<Workbook>();
    foreach (Workbook x in me)
        if (condition(x)) list.Add(x);
    return list;
}
```

Why does one work across assembly boundaries and the other not?

---

Correction, neither method was working in that particular application. However, I was able to get the desired result by creating a ToArray() extension method for ListObjects, and then calling that in my application and calling LINQ methods on the array.

Why are strongly typed lists not counted as generic types?

How is ListObject[] not just syntactic sugar for Array{ListObject}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the shallowest answer is quite simple - when arrays were added to the language, there were no generics.

Now, every array is derived from the type `Array` - however, without generics (which weren't available), there would be no way to implement type safety, not to mention the performance implications. So instead, arrays are somewhere between a primitive type, and a class derived from `Array`.

Of course, in the end, there is no meaningful difference between `T[]` and `Array<T>` - in fact, you could say that arrays were generic from the very beginning, long before "proper" generics were implemented.

`List<T>` is a completely separate class - it just uses `T[]` internally to store the actual data. It's non-generic counterpart is `ArrayList` - again, created before generics made their way into the language and CLR.

Finally, you shouldn't need to go through the hoops you are - the reason the LINQ extension methods don't work for you is that collections like `ListObjects` do not implement `IEnumerable<ListObject>`, but only `IEnumerable`. The designers of .NET were aware of this, of course, so you can easily convert the enumerable as appropriate - for example, `listObjects.OfType<ListObject>().Where(i => ...)`. No need to write your own extension methods ;)

Comment: Yes, I suppose I already knew that.  It's an ugly inconsistency, but at least its a loophole for generic collections of embedded interop types.  Thanks.

Comment: @CarlFriedRiceGauss The problem with that is nicely explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765685/are-we-unable-to-use-interop-objects-in-generic-objects-in-net-4-0 - you can turn off the embedding, or use the other hack :)